# ASP.NET Web App interface is empty when running in VS Community 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, gruntjs, rider

I have an ASP.NET application that uses grunt to generate static files in wwwroot. When launching application through Visual Studio 2022 (in any configuration), app interface does not appear.  Browser shows generated html is empty and sources do not contain files.

[image]

If running project through Rider, then interface appears. Sources contain the css and js folders that grunt generates in wwwroot. And besides, in output can see Get-requests to these static files (these requests are not run from VS).

[image]

Reinstalling VS doesn't help, including resetting options.